# An error while running subprocess cordova, but no explanation

Tags: ios, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, compiler-errors

I'm compiling my ionic angular build with `ionic cordova build --prod --release` for iOS and I'm getting this error:

Edit: I rerun my command with --verbose, and this is the outcome I got:

```
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared iOS project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at /Users/meghan/sandbox/Parks/TSP_Mobile_App/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:54:45
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/meghan/sandbox/Parks/TSP_Mobile_App/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:52:44
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/meghan/sandbox/Parks/TSP_Mobile_App/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:50:57
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/meghan/sandbox/Parks/TSP_Mobile_App/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:45:28
    at _fulfilled (/Users/meghan/sandbox/Parks/TSP_Mobile_App/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /Users/meghan/sandbox/Parks/TSP_Mobile_App/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/meghan/sandbox/Parks/TSP_Mobile_App/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build ios --release --verbose exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +0ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +36ms
```

This is literally the entirety of the error, and I can't find anything remotely close to it. Any ideas?

Comment: Run you command with --verbose and re edit your question with the output it shows.

Comment: @MostafaHarb I rerun the command with --verbose. thanks.

Comment: Did you try to remove the build and rebuild it? And what is the plugin you used for phone call?

Comment: @MostafaHarb I removed package-lock and node modules again and rebuilt it, still the same error. For calls, we're using CallNumber from @ionic-native/call-number. Is this what you're asking about?

<plugin name="mx.ferreyra.callnumber" spec="0.0.2" />
<plugin name="call-number" spec="^1.0.1" />

Comment: Does it fail to build or fail to run on emulator? Since in the error there are lines related for ios emulator . Plus did you use toLowerCase() in your project or its related to files listed in error? If its related to the files listed enter to each file of them and see if there are lines in red or the problem in the lines they are pointing on. And tell me whats happening.

Comment: @MostafaHarb it fails to build. The emulator from XCode works perfectly fine. The toLowerCase() is related to the files listed. There are no lines in red, the only thing I see strange is this that it's looking for 'unavailable': 

device.availability.toLowerCase().indexOf('unavailable') < 0)

Comment: Is your cordova-ios version 5.+ or less than 5? If less update (using ionic cordova platform add ios@latest but before remove the build) and it will be solved else tell me.

Comment: If its done tell me so i add it as an answer .

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, the build succeeded!! :)

Comment: I've added an answer, so you could vote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your cordova ios version
If its les then 5.+ then remove your build and rebuild using

```
ionic cordova build ios@latest
```